# How does modulus affect the regularity of language?

Tags: automata, regular-languages, finite-automata

the question is as follows, further the notation used are standard as used in theory of computation
$$L = \big\{ w : w \in \{a,b\}^*,\ |n(a) - n(b)| = 2k\}\,.$$

Beware 'K' is not a fixed integer its a set of natural number , so 2k means all natural nunbers divisible by 2 and so on for 3k , 4k... .I think the above language is irregular or its finite automata can't be formed. Firstly the above question in basic language can be thought of as modulus of difference of number of $a$ and number of $b$ is divisible by $2$ or is even , similar to this reasoning we can extend this to more general like $3k$, $4k$, $5k$,... and so on. Secondly we know that any condition which have comprise the difference between the symbols would have infinite possible comparison between symbols, like an equation of
 $n(a) - n(b) =0/1/2/3...$ needs infinite states of finite automata which makes them irregular.

But here with the use of modulus it seems no different as here also we will need many comparison between symbols.

Thirdly its more of a general question like when define regularity of language $L$ over condition like,  $n(a) - n(b)\bmod 3 =0$, we say the all strings can be classified as having either remainder $0$,$1$,$2$ which by using Myhill-Nerode theorem proves the language regular. But why cant we use the same analogy over the relation like $n(a) -n(b)=2$ saying the all the strings would either have a difference $2$ or not. Further if you could answer the regularity of $n(a)- n(b) = 2k$, also how does taking modulus effect its regularity and how does it makes the states of finite automata finite which before applying modulus were infinite if you could a graphical representation would be appreciated.

Comment: "$L = \big\{ w : w \in \{a,b\}^*,\ |n(a) - n(b)| = 2k\}$", you said. Do you mean $L_k = \big\{ w : w \in \{a,b\}^*,\ |n(a) - n(b)| = 2k\}$ for some fixed non-negative integer $k$, or $L = \big\{ w : w \in \{a,b\}^*,\ |n(a) - n(b)| \text { is even}\}$? Apparently, people are answering your question according to either one of these interpretations.

Comment: @Apass.Jack yeah the language described is just a single case of a generalisation but it answers only one aspect my whole problem which have a many  small yet important aspect connected to the language L but here the have just made an automata of language and that it @ david had said for generalisation but iam awaitng his further response

Comment: Sorry, which one do you mean? I asked a question of two choices. But you answered with yes. Once again, do you mean $L_k$ for a fixed $k$ or do you mean the difference is even? Or do you think those two choices are the same (to me, those two choices are very different)?

Comment: @Apass.Jack i request you to read question once again and i think you will find that i have asked more  than two thing of which some being like , whether is the difference ( N(a) -N(b) )is even(or divisible by 2) ,but i have asked the same in more general form like is the difference( N(b) -N(b) ) is divisible by 3 to which i have written an equation of form N(a) -N(b) = 3k , where 3k being set of natural numbers. i thought that you will understand but my bad you did not . so can you answer now that whether for ( N(a)-N(b) ) =3k  (where k is set of natural number ) we can form a finite automata

Comment: i will upvote it if found good

Comment: @aknautiyal's answer is pretty good In fact. I advise you to up-vote and accept it. Unless you have any further doubt, which should be another question probably, I will not write another answer that will be basically a duplicate.

Comment: @Apass.Jack his answer is ok for |n(a) -n(b) | = 2k , but when asked about N(a)-N(b) = 2k he said that we can not form a general  automata , so that is in fact weird , as we can form one with 3 states representing {-1,0,1} .please beware that -1 is is nothing but a state where the string like , b,bbb goes but this only means that they should not be accepted i.e after reaching bbb the FA should reach a state that is not final . but saying existence of bbb does not satisfy the nature of equation  is absurd. so yeah we can form an automata for  n(a) -N(b) = 2k, 3k, 4k,...

Comment: @Apass.Jack the answer by aknautiyal is wrong just make the automata for |N(a)-N(b)| = 3n and its wrong

Comment: @Apass.Jack there?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be assuming that, to determine whether $n(a)-n(b)$ is a multiple of $m$ requires us to computer $n(a)$ and $n(b)$, subtract them, and then calculate the remainder. You're correct that a finite automaton can't do that, but it's not the only way.

The first thing to note is that you can computer $n(a)-n(b)$ directly. Initially, you've seen no $a$s or $b$s so the difference is zero. Each time you see an $a$, the difference increases by one; each time you see a $b$, the difference decreases by one. OK, that's a bit smarter but it still requires us to compute the value $n(a)-n(b)$, which could still be arbitrarily big, so still can't be done with a finite automaton.

The second thing to note is that, because of the way that modular arithmetic works,
$$(x-y)\bmod m = ((x\bmod m) - (y\bmod m)) \bmod m\,.$$
In other words, you can do everything modulo $m$. Each time you read an $a$, the difference increases by one *modulo $m$*. and each time you read a $b$, it decreases by one *modulo $m$*.

This means that you can recognize the language with an automaton with $m$ states: one for each value of $n(a)-n(b)\bmod m$.

Comment: ok i have no problem with modulo but , by  your reasoning i assume that we can formulate an automata of n(a) -n(b) = 2k, 3k,.. even for the conditions like |n(a)- n(b)| = even, odd, 3k,2k,. (remember i have used modulus function that is different from modulo function) with modulus the reason being that the difference between a and b being divisible by 2 without any order in occurrence  of  a and b. but when we say , n(a)- n(b) =2k we say that the order of occurence of a and b matters . is that right? , also we can say that (n(a)-n(b)) mod 2 =0, have same language as (n(a) -n(b) ) mod 2 =0 ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed the modulus. I don't have time to look at this now but I'll try to see later if it makes any difference.

Comment: one more thing that we cannot form finite automata for n(a) - n(b) = 2k, 3k,4k...and so on

Comment: i find your answer incorrect if you are saying that for N(a)-N(b) = 2k, 3k... we can not form an automata. beacuse we can

Answer (score 2):

For the given language
 $|n(a) - n(b)|$ will be even only if either $n(a)$ and $n(b)$ are both odd or both even.

In any case the total no. of symbols should be even.

So we have two states:
q0 : where the total no. of symbols is even (accepted state)

q1: where the total no. of symbols is odd.

[image: Fig1. for |n(a) - n(b)| = 2k]

In general:
$|n(a) - n(b)| = mk\ $ for some $k\ge0$ if and only if $n(a)\mod(m)  = n(b)\mod(m),$ i.e. both number of 'a's and number of 'b's have same remainder when divided by $m$.

now difference between $n(a)\mod(m)$ and $n(b)\mod(m)$ can be $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, \cdots, m-1$.

So there will be $m$ states, each representing the difference : $n(a) - n(b) \mod(m)$. The state diagram will be something like:
[image: Fig2. |n(a) - n(b)| = mk]

Comment: if you could then , could you tell me that whether there exists an automata for n(a) -n(b) = 2k,3k,4k...

Comment: also bear that here the equation is simplified but by your logic  can we say that there exist a  finite automata  for  |n(a) -n(b) |= 2k,3k,4k... ?,  which inturn implies some relation to be occurred with n(a)-n(b) =2k,3k,4k....

Comment: @rajendra I understand a finite automata as a tool, like a blank piece of paper, on which you can note down one quantity at a time. Something like a programmable register that can store some value, but only one value. In the expression with modulus i need just the difference,, based on that I can decide whether a string matches. In case without modulus, i need to keep track of both a's and b's and that the  difference is how far from multiple of k.

Comment: so that means  N(a) -N(b) = 2k ,3k ...are not regular and there automata cant be formed ?

Comment: @rajendra Iam a little confused here. when we say anything say "x" is a multiple of m and we  write x = mk, does it not imply k is a whole number? If it does then, we need to have |n(a) -n(b)|on the left hand side.

Comment: @rajendra, as I cannot comment on the question as I do not have that previledge yet, I am commenting here....  {w:w∈{a,b}∗, n(a)−n(b)=3k} where k >= 0. So right handside cannot be negative. How can the left side be negative then , and thats why all (N(a) - N(b)) < 0 are not valid, thus | N(a) - N(b) | is the correct thing to be... for example say a string "bbb". Here N(a) is 0 and N(b) is 3 , N(a) - N(b) = -3, can we write it to be in form of 3 k (k >=0), No. So this string does not belong to the given language. In fact, even if you write N(a) - N(b) it essentially means |N(a) - N(b)|.

Comment: Also, Here is a subtle point you had mentioned in the question standard notation used, generally when we say x = 3k, we mean k is a whole number, not a natural number. If you are saying k is a natural number, then its totally a different language,  if it is, k cannot be zero. So all those instances where n(a) and n(b) are equal, cannot be part of the language. However the logic that N(a) - N(b) will essentially be same  as |N(a) - N(b)| even if k is a natural number.

Comment: ok thanks , so this means that we can and can not form an automata for N(a) - N(b) =2k , depending upon the values of k , like k whole number then we can as it falls in the category same that of |N(a)-N(b) | and if k is real number then we cant . i must say you have thought very hard over it so its indeed correct. BTW i figured the answer quite a while. I want to add one thing perhaps you are thinking ok but please beware that finite automata reads the string from left to right , you may ask what about it . reason being

Comment: continuing here, reason being that apart from the fact that 'bbb' does not belong to the FA but , FA should have a non final state for it else string like 'bbbaaaaa' are also not accepted. so FA check the strings from left to right but in that scenerio it rejects untill bbb but after the full scanning of string it would be in final state. so for N(a) -N(b) = 2k,3k,4k,,, we cannot form FA not that the reason you give (but you tried well) but the fact that it will have 3 equivalent classes for negative length string (eg, bb ,b, i have loosely used negative length)

Comment: so , we have total 5 equivalent class according to  all the string depending upon there remainders namely {-2,-1,0,1,2 }, i have used equation N(a)-N(b)= 3k here. now when you take modulus of the above classes then we get three classes (0,1,2) and your answer just revolve around it . so yeah we can get FA for N(a)-N(b) = 3k . i hope you get clearer. i am sorry that in above aomment i mentioned that we cannot create